# Objective-c / Swift method and variables names after compilation

Tags: objective-c, swift, llvm

It's obvious that objective-c method names are exactly the same after compilation, since cocoa has been made to be highly readable in development but as well in runtime. But how does it apply on variable names ? Only method names are the same after compilation ?
And how it looks like in Swift ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i have checked Objective-c and Swift all methods and global variables are very similar to ones used in code. The best way is to not use obvious one or just write simple obfuscation script as i did. Indeed article pasted here by @Berik is interesting. Great idea is to use custom compiler but it bring some more complicated troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Swift mangles the names required in runtime to avoid naming collisions. Names that are not required in runtime can be pruned (depending on your compiler settings).

There are tools available to de-mangle the generated names. For further reading, refer here:
https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-08-15-swift-name-mangling.html

FWIW, the Objective-C compiler also mangles names, but swift's mangling is more intricate to allow for method overloading etc.

Comment: Very interesting article about swift. I think it has fulfilled my Swift-part question. But im not still sure how variable names are managed with Objective-c.Thank you